# Flutter error while adding web support to app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I just found out that I can change my flutter app to a website without writing external code. I decided to test it on my app but I got this error and I have no idea how to fix it. I followed the steps on the ["website"](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) but still I get the error. My stacktrace is :-

```
This application is not configured to build on the web.
To add web support to a project, run `flutter create .`.
Launching lib\main.dart on Web Server in debug mode...
Syncing files to device Web Server...
org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'package:discountapp/generated_plugin_registrant.dart';
       ^
org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart:11:3: Error: Method not found: 'registerPlugins'.
  registerPlugins(webPluginRegistry);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

I run flutter create . and it says

```
C:\Users\Hemant\AndroidStudioProjects\discountapp\ios>flutter create .
Recreating project ....
Wrote 3 files.

All done!
[√] Flutter: is fully installed. (Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices: is fully installed. (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web: is fully installed.
[√] Android Studio: is fully installed. (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device: is fully installed. (3 available)

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd .
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in .\lib\main.dart.


C:\Users\Hemant\AndroidStudioProjects\discountapp\ios>flutter create .
Recreating project ....
Wrote 3 files.

All done!
[√] Flutter: is fully installed. (Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices: is fully installed. (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web: is fully installed.
[√] Android Studio: is fully installed. (version 4.0)
[√] Connected device: is fully installed. (3 available)

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd .
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in .\lib\main.dart.
```

Running flutter run will run it on my phone. I will provide any code needed. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run `flutter create .` in application's root folder, but not in `ios` subfolder.

Comment: I am doing some cleaning right now. I will get back to you as soon as I am free

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename `ios` folder to `_ios`
2. Run this command in your Terminal: `flutter create --platforms=web .`
3. Rename back `_ios` folder to `ios`

This will write all needed files to run your app on the browser.